# PHP MYSQL - ID AS category SUB_ID as Comment

Tags: php, mysql, comments, categories, article

I cant figure out how to get comments underneath mysql db entries..

For example There is one article witch id is `1` and then there are some (for example 3) comments in that article (ID - 1) `[ARTICLE_ID][CATEGORY]`
And the comments are like: `[ID][ARTICLE_ID]`
..

so it is like

| ID | SUB_ID | TITLE....
|   1  |   123      |   THIS IS A ARTICLE
 |   2  |      1         |       COMMENT TO ARTICLE 1
 |   3  |      1          |     COMMENT 2 to article 1
|   4  |      1           |    Comment 3 to Article 1
AND CEN_TYPE for all of thesese IDs, 1,2,3,4 is `forumentry`


I've tryed like this:

1. SELECT everthing from CNT_Entries_A WHERE CEN_TYPE is like `forumentry` - so everthing is fine here, but it doesnt put comments underneath (logically)
2. Putting all ID's AND SUB_ID's in to a array's
3. making foreach cycle, inside that checking if current ID is equal to arrays value if it is, check if that ID is in array - if is not then printing it out and putting it to an array..
4. SAME THING to SUB ID

Comment: Is there a reason for putting articles and comments into the same table?

Comment: @VolkerK i wouldnt make articles, comments like that, but the table was already there.. so i have to get information out.

Comment: The condition of the first query is not refelected by the table layout you've posted. CEN_TYPE is like forumentry?

Comment: @VolkerK  CEN_TYPE for all of thesese IDs, 1,2,3,4 is `forumentry`

Comment: can u put the expected result to make it easier to understand from the given scenarion n rough schema of tables?

Comment: the sub_id for 2,3,4 will be actually the article id.Similarly what will the sub_id be representing for row 1 which is an article?

Comment: @AngelinNadar it is Category id..

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend to split the data into two data tables:

**Articles**
`article_id    |    text`

**Comments**
`comment_id    |    article_id    |    comment`

Then You won't have problem to do a simple `SELECT` + `LEFT JOIN` query...

Answer (score 0):

This will give result as article and their comments so that u can then loop over:

find the implementation [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f91e/2)

```
SELECT c1 . * , c2 . * 
FROM comments AS c1
JOIN comments AS c2 ON ( c1.id = c2.sub_id
AND c1.id != c2.id ) 
WHERE c1.cen_type =  'forumentry'


+----+--------+-------------------+------------+----+--------+----------------------+------------+
| id | sub_id | title             | cen_type   | id | sub_id | title                | cen_type   |
+----+--------+-------------------+------------+----+--------+----------------------+------------+
|  1 |      1 | THIS IS A ARTICLE | forumentry |  2 |      1 | COMMENT TO ARTICLE 1 | forumentry |
|  1 |      1 | THIS IS A ARTICLE | forumentry |  3 |      1 | COMMENT 2 to article | forumentry |
|  1 |      1 | THIS IS A ARTICLE | forumentry |  4 |      1 | Comment 3 to Article | forumentry |
+----+--------+-------------------+------------+----+--------+----------------------+------------+
```

Comment: where are you storing the category info as u said the sub_id is the category_id?

Comment: also in that table....  but SUB_ID for the category is 120, mann, i hate this db, so dumb

Comment: I hope u were expecting this answer